# How can I create single axes labels for an entire figure created with ImageGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a plot with matplotlib's `ImageGrid` helper class.  Here's the code below:

```
from mpl_tookits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

fig = figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi=300)
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 4), axes_pad=1, aspect=False)
for gridax, (i, sub) in zip(grid, enumerate(eyelink_data)):
    subnum = i + start_with

     # format data
    xdat = sub['x'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]
    ydat = sub['y'][(sub['in_trl'] == True) & (sub['x'].notnull()) & (sub['y'].notnull())]

    # plot
    gridax.hist2d(xdat, ydat, bins=[np.linspace(-.005, .005, num=1000), np.linspace(-.005, .005, num=1000)])
    gridax.plot(0, 0, 'ro')  # origin

show()
```

I looked to [this cookbook page](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Multiple_Subplots_with_One_Axis_Label) for information on how to set a single x and y label for the entire figure, but these recipes seem only to apply to standard figures with standard subplots.

I also took a peek at some of `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider.LocatableAxes`'s methods, but nothing jumped out at me.  *Idem* for the methods in `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_grid.ImageGrid`.

Does anybody know how I can do this using an `ImageGrid`?

Comment: at the moment there is no direct support for this feature in matplotlib. You can play with `text` or axis lables. However there is a [PR on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1519) for this.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano, could you explain how I might mess around with `text` or `axis`? What should I be looking at?

Comment: I'll try to come up with an answer later. By the way: which version of matplotlib are you using. On v 1.2.0 there is no `ImageGrid` in `mpl_tookits.axes_grid1`: there is a `AxisGrid`

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano, Thanks, I'd appreciate that!  I'm using `1.3.x`

Comment: does my answer do what you want?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano, it looks great!  I haven't had time to try it yet, but I'll be sure to let you know how it goes (I upvoted it in the meantime).  I appreciate your checking up, though =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this github pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1519) I tried a possible implementation of figure-wide x and y labels (I'm glad that I'm not the only one that would like to have such functionality.

This code recaps the main points of the PR implementation and produces [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pslap.png). Tested against matplotlib master fetched today (18.03.2013).

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 4), axes_pad=1, aspect=False)

#get the extent of the largest box containing all the axes/subplots
extents = np.array([a.get_position().extents for a in grid])  #all axes extents
bigextents = np.empty(4)   
bigextents[:2] = extents[:,:2].min(axis=0)
bigextents[2:] = extents[:,2:].max(axis=0)

#text to mimic the x and y label. The text is positioned in the middle 
labelpad=0.08  #distance between the external axis and the text
xlab_t = fig.text((bigextents[2]+bigextents[0])/2, bigextents[1]-labelpad, 'x label',
    horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment = 'bottom')
ylab_t = fig.text( bigextents[0]-labelpad, (bigextents[3]+bigextents[1])/2, 'y label',
    rotation='vertical', horizontalalignment = 'left', verticalalignment = 'center')
```

If you work interactively or want to encapsulate in a function/class, you can get rid of the old label with `[xy]lab_t.set_visible(False)` before drawing new labels (there is a `text.remove()` method but is not yet implemented).

With this approach there are a couple of caveats:

1. does not work with `plt.tight_layout`: this is due to the fact that this method is specific to `subplots` not to to `matplotlib.Figure` objects
2. a few month ago there was an idea/PR to include all `artists` when saving a figure with `bbox_inches='tight'`, but I don't know the status of this.